# How to run multiple functions with sleep times parallel and infinitely

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, infinite

This is the actual code

```
while($true){

$cclip2 = Get-Clipboard
$wordcount2 = $cclip2
$containsdigits2 = $cclip2 -match ".*\d+.*"
$countresult2=([regex]::Matches($wordcount2, " " )).count

if ($countresult2 -eq "24" -And $cclip2 -ne $cclip3 -And $containsdigits2 -eq 0) {$cclip2 >> C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2


$cclip3 = Get-Clipboard
$wordcount = $cclip3
$containsdigits3 = $cclip3 -match ".*\d+.*"
$countresult=([regex]::Matches($wordcount, " " )).count

if ($countresult -eq "24" -And $cclip3 -ne $cclip2 -And $containsdigits3 -eq 0) {$cclip3 >> C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

}



while($true){
gc C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt| sort | get-unique > C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelpSort1.txt
Start-Sleep -Seconds 200

}
```

The 2nd while true statement never runs obviously its outside of the loop, and this is my problem whats the best way to implement things.

Comment: Is your ultimate goal here to get them both to output to the console screen, or something else?

Comment: Something else, this code was just an example, maybe I am asking how to run 2 functions infinitely whilst adhering to individual timed parenthesis, Do I have to define them in script-blocks and use start job?

Comment: If you just need them to truck along in the background, `Start-Job` is an excellent way, yes

Comment: I want to run both while true statements in an async infinite loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I have seen to run multi-threaded PowerShell programs is by using the `Start-Job` command.

For this case in particular, it would look like this:

```
# start the second  thread before entering the infinite loop
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        while($true){
            gc C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt| sort | get-unique > C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelpSort1.txt
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 200

        }
    }

# start initial loop
while($true){

    $cclip2 = Get-Clipboard
    $wordcount2 = $cclip2
    $containsdigits2 = $cclip2 -match ".*\d+.*"
    $countresult2=([regex]::Matches($wordcount2, " " )).count

    if ($countresult2 -eq "24" -And $cclip2 -ne $cclip3 -And $containsdigits2 -eq 0) {$cclip2 >> C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt}

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2


    $cclip3 = Get-Clipboard
    $wordcount = $cclip3
    $containsdigits3 = $cclip3 -match ".*\d+.*"
    $countresult=([regex]::Matches($wordcount, " " )).count

    if ($countresult -eq "24" -And $cclip3 -ne $cclip2 -And $containsdigits3 -eq 0) {
        $cclip3 >> C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

}
```

Alternatively, you could use `Start-Job` for both loops (to be consistent).